# The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type AlertDemo

Tags: java, android, vibration

i use `getSystemService(String)` in this way that i want this activity to start vibration for 1 second. However, the error say the title

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
  mVibrator.vibrate(1000);
}
```

Thank you for answering!

Comment: What is the parent of the class where you're calling this from? It is an `Activity`?

Comment: public class AlertDemo extends DialogFragment {

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you need to call this method from an activity ... so change above call to:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  mVibrator = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
  mVibrator.vibrate(1000);
}
```

Comment: (@gunar, I'm sure you must have figured it by now) 
For anybody else wondering about getActivity()  it lets you access the parent activity of the fragment. This is a very useful method which you can use whenever there is an issue related to "Context" in your fragment.